# cannot import tensorflow-gpu dll load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I couldn't solve my problem with previous similar questions.
I installed tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0 along python 3.6, cuda 10 and cudnn 7.4.2. 
now according to this page, these are compatible and tested:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations

when importing, this is the error its returning:

```
>>> import tensorflow
2020-02-05 15:17:43.900905: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\p6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\p6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\p6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\p6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\p6\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\p6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\p6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\p6\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have already tried reinstalling all of them. i've also checked and the PATH is also added in environment variables. got these errors on latest version of python, tensorflow-gpu, cuda, cudnn too.

could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried installing/updating Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2019 as a common solution for this? And, or upgrading the python 3.6 to 3.6.8 or higher?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possible reasons for Tensorflow installation issues in windows

- You need to install the MSVC 2019 redistributable from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
- Your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions
- Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits
- There is a library that is in a different location/not installed on your system that cannot be loaded.